# Spring MVC + jQuery Datatables + JSON Response

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, datatables

I have a Spring MVC application using jQuery Datatables to render the data.
Here are my classes and javascript code

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {
    private int empId ;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName ;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**EmployeeResponse.java**

```
public class EmployeeResponse {

    private List<Employee> empList ; 

    // getters and setters

}
```

**EmployeeController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class EmployeeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get-all-employee", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    @ResponseBody
    public EmployeeResponse getAllEmployee(HttpServletRequest request) {
        EmployeeResponse response = new EmployeeResponse();
        try {

            response = getAllEmployeeList(); // returns response object

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("DCConsoleController::createNewStream exception: " + com.priceline.utils.StringUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            return null;
        }
        return response ; 
    }
}
```

**emp.jsp**

```
<div class="row">
    <table id="ldapStreamTable" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Emp Id</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

**emp.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#appTable').DataTable( {
        "sDom" : domSetting,
        "oLanguage" : {
            "sLengthMenu" : "_MENU_ records per page",
            "sSearch" : "<span class='add-on'><i class='icon-search'></i></span>Search Application:",
            "sZeroRecords" : "No matching records found",
        },
        "iDisplayLength" : 10,
        "aLengthMenu" : [
                [ 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, -1 ],
                [ 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, "All" ] ],
        "aaSorting" : [ [ 0, 'asc' ] ],
        'sAjaxSource': '{context}/admin/get-all-employee',
        [Pending here]
    });
});
```

What should I do to get the response as json and apply/use render methods for each column to render the data into the table?

[Note: looks like I can't use aoColumns' with mData for each column because my json response is list of employee objects]

Update - 1: Sample json below

```
{"empList":[{"empId":3,"firstName":"Kiran","lastName":"Kumar"},{"empId":1,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith"},{"empId":0,"firstName":"Sachin","lastName":"Kumar"}]}
```

Comment: Have you looked into using Gson or a similar library?

Comment: My response from controller is already in json format using Jackson API. What I am unable to figure out is how to bind the json response which is a List<Employee> objects into the columns on the UI

Comment: Could you post your `json` response?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao - updated the question with sample json response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've kept your sample `ajax` data in **[`github`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kshkrao3/JsonFileSample/master/EmployeeTables.json)** and gave it as a `ajax` source. You keep that part to your `method` which returns `json` response, but instead of `empList` as base root in `json` response replace it with `data` as I've done in the above `github` `json` file. Now apart from `ajaxSource` you need to map `columns` to your `dataTables` as below:

```
"columns": [
         { "data": "empId"},//should match column value in json file
         { "data": "firstName"},//should match column value in json file
         { "data": "lastName"}//should match column value in json file
]
```

**[A Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ycbaqvnz/1/)**

Comment: I just figured another way to do it by setting the "sAjaxDataProp" : 'streamList' and "aoColumns" : [ {mDataProp: "empId"}, {mDataProp: "lastName"},{mDataProp: "firstName"}   ]. However, I generate a button using mRender option, how can I bind the event to it, after the table is rendered. fnRowCallback ?

Comment: Give your button a `class` and add event to that `class`

Comment: Thatz exactly what I did, but somehow the click event is not getting registered.

Comment: I think you are not doing `event delegation` here.. Since you are rendering the button controls on later part to the `DOM` you must do `event delegation` like attaching control some `element` which contains `button` element and which has been registered on `DOM` load.. For ex: `document`, which is the root. So you do `$(document).on('click','.yourButtonClass',function(){//click event methods});`

Comment: Sure, that would probably work as well. But I ended up using fnDrawCallback and binding the click event to the class like you mentioned earlier. Using fnDrawCallback option seems to be a cleane approach. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)